# When using Jetpack view binding, should I keep referring to ids through R.id.something, or use binding.something.id instead?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I want to retrieve the id of a Layout inside of one of my layout xmls, and it's possible to use both
R.id.* and the binding for this - details below.
Which is the preferred way?

Given the following structure:

```
app  
|-- java.org.romco.appname  
|  |-- MainActivity.kt  
|-- res.layout  
|  |-- main_activity.xml  
|  |-- main_content.xml
```

Let's say my main_activity.xml is a CoordinatorLayout and includes the main_content.xml with a defined id of "main_content", such as:

```
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

My content_main.xml then contains a FrameLayout with a defined if of "task_details_container", such as:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/task_details_container" />
```

Following the official guides, the binding in MainActivity.kt would be created as:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mainActivityBinding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mainActivityBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(mainActivityBinding.root)
    }
```

If I now want to refer to the FrameView inside of my content_main.xml, how do I go about it?
Should i use what I'd normally use, so R.id.task_details_container, or is it preferred to use the binding to retrieve the ID now that I have it available? If I try to log it in onCreate, the output is the same:

```
        val id1 = R.id.task_details_container
        val id2 = mainActivityBinding.mainContent.taskDetailsContainer.id

        Log.d("MainActivity", "R id = $id1, binding id = $id2")
```

Log output:

> D/MainActivity: R id = 2131231072, binding id = 2131231072

From what I've found so far:

- here's a video where they introduce view binding, but they only mention it as a way to avoid using findViewById: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=td3Kd7fOROw&t=1756s
- This article walks us through using view binding, in both activities and fragments, but again, seemingly only as a way to avoid findViewById. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-view-binding-to-replace-findviewbyid-c83942471fc
- The official doc covers pretty much the same as the article: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

But none of these talk about whether using the bound id is better than using R.id.*.
My guess is that using R.id.* is preferred, since not all elements have to be view-bound and therefore, for the sake of consistency, I can use R.id.* everywhere, where as I possibly can't use binding where the property is not accessible. But as I said, it's just a guess and I'd like to hear a wiser opinion on this.

Comment: can't tell without knowing what you need the ID for

Comment: no need to use findViewId just use binding.ViewId or button or textView id and acess it directly like binding.tvName.text="Any"

Comment: I'm trying to programatically add a fragment into the container:
`supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()  
            .replace(mainActivityBinding.mainContent.taskDetailsContainer.id, newFragment)
`   
---- OR  
`supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.task_details_container, newFragment)
            .commit() `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use View Binding. It is more efficient than `findViewById`. Every time you call `findViewById()`, the Android system traverses the entire view hierarchy at runtime to find the view. Whereas View Binding traverses the view hierarchy only once. For a large view hierarchy, using `findViewById` can noticeably slow down the app for the user.

If you are using view ids for anything other than calling `findViewById()`, is safe to use `R.id.view_id` instead `binding.view.id`. Both have the same performance characteristics

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but R.id.something is not the same as findViewById(R.id.something) - I'm not using findViewById, I'm just trying to get the id of the item.

Comment: i completed my answer